# After iptables to nftables conversion, unable to connect to http nextcloud server and apt doesn't connect

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, apt, nftables, nextcloud

I want to enable access to my nextcloud server and be able to use apt update. I used to be able to before my iptables to nftables conversion. However, after the conversion, its no longer possible. Pinging Google  and server access via SSH still works though. Please help me understand what's wrong here.

Here is my current *nftables.conf*:

```
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                iifname "lo" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                ip saddr 127.0.0.1 ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp sport 3310 ct state established,related counter packets
0 bytes 0 accept
                tcp sport 587 ct state established,related counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                udp sport 123 ct state established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "eno1" ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 tcp sport { 80, 443 } ct state established,related counter
packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "eno1" ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 tcp dport 443 ct state established,new counter packets 0 by
tes 0 accept
                iifname "eno1" ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 tcp dport 59777 ct state established,new counter packets 0
bytes 0 accept
                ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 tcp dport 59777 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                icmp type echo-request counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                icmp type echo-reply counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "eno1" udp sport 53 ct state established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "eno1" counter packets 2 bytes 178 log prefix "Dropped Packet: "
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                tcp dport 587 ct state established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain port-scanning {
                tcp flags rst / fin,syn,rst,ack limit rate 1/second burst 2 packets counter packets 0 bytes 0 retu
rn
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        }
}
```